# Using a bundt pan in place of loaf pans

Tags: baking

If a recipe calls for the use of two loaf pans, would it be ok to use a bundt pan instead?

Comment: What are you making? Is your bundt pan twice the size of the asked for loaf pans? Normally, you can always switch molds, if 1) you don't mind the shape and if 2) the mold is large enough.

Answer (score 2):

For almost all baking applications, you can freely substitute a bundt pan for a loaf pan, especially for quick breads like banana bread or pumpkin bread.  I have often made my Thanksgiving cornbread in a bundt to get a more attractive presentation.

You may wish to measure the capacity of your bundt, which is easiest to do by filling it with water to the same level you would batter, and then measuring that.  This will let you compare the volume to your loaf pans.

If you have extra batter after the bundt is filled, you can always make a few muffins to use up any excess.  (Just leave the unused muffin cups empty; it is fine, despite the advise some five to fill them with water.)

Depending on your particular bundt, it may take a little while longer (usually) to bake through than loaf pans will, so make sure you test for doneness instead of relying on timing.

For quick breads, the toothpick test is usually a good one (does a toothpick stuck into the thickest part come out with only a very few slightly moist crumbs on it).

---

For yeast raised breads, it should also work, although you will definitely want to do your final proofing in the bundt so that the dough can expand into the mold.  You should also use a fairly traditional bundt, not one of the modern ones with many small cavities that the dough might not work its way into.

Again, make sure you are testing for doneness (most yeast raised bread is done around 198 F to 202 F), rather than relying on time.

Comment: The water in muffin tins is so that they cook more evenly -- if you fill one side of the pan and not the other, you'll have heat conduction from the empty side that will cook muffins on that side faster than the ones further away.

Comment: @Joe It turns out to not be true...

Comment: http://www.americastestkitchenfeed.com/cooking-science/2013/06/when-baking-fewer-than-12-muffins-or-cupcakes-do-you-need-to-fill-the-empty-cups-with-water/

Comment: I have baked literally  millions of muffins and never witnessed them getting darker next to the empty cups.

Comment: NO, it doesn't tkae longer in a bundt over a loaf pan. The opposite is true, due to hole in center and somewhat thinner and rounded shape...will bake faster

Comment: The shape of the pan helps, but the timing could still be longer or shorter depending on the exact dimensions of the bread in each type of pan.  You can get an idea of the timing by measuring the thickness of the bread in the narrowest dimension.  If it's thicker in your bundt pan than in your loaf pan, the bundt pan will make it take longer.  If it's thinner, it should take less time.  Since there are so many sizes and shapes of bundt pans, and different recipes produce different volumes, it could go either way.